# Подключение клиента ActiveMQ по SSL

Tags: c++, linux, сертификат, activemq

Имею простой клиент для высылания сообщений для ActiveMQ на C++ очень похожий на [этот пример](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/example.html).

Встала задача подключения клиента по SSL

Получил файлы `amq-client_cert.cer` (**сертификат**), `amq-client.ks` (**keyStore**), `amq-client.ts` (**trustStore**)

Согласно [документации](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/how-do-i-use-the-ssl-transport.html) ключи должны иметь формат `.pem`

Нашел [тут](https://www.calazan.com/how-to-convert-a-java-keystore-jks-to-pem-format/) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652916/converting-a-java-keystore-into-pem-format), как приобразовать `.ks` в `.pem`

**Не** нашел, как преобразовывать `.ts` в `.pem` (и надо ли?)

Согласно [документации](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/example.html), код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
System::setProperty( "decaf.net.ssl.keyStore", "<path>/client.pem" );
System::setProperty( "decaf.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password" );
System::setProperty( "decaf.net.ssl.trustStore", "<path>/rootCA.pem" );
```

После преобразования .ks в .pem мой код выглядит примерно так:

```
decaf::lang::System::setProperty("decaf.net.ssl.keyStore", "/home/xxx/Keys/sascomm/myapp.pem");
decaf::lang::System::setProperty("decaf.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "xxx");
decaf::lang::System::setProperty("decaf.net.ssl.trustStore","/home/xxx/Keys/sascomm/amq-client.ts");
decaf::lang::System::setProperty("decaf.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","xxx");
```

стало лучше, чем когда пытался подсунуть для проперции `decaf.net.ssl.keyStore` файл `.ks` (исчезло `PEM_read_bio:no start line`), но все равно не соединяет, вижу только строчку `Error occurred while accessing an OpenSSL library method:` и дальше пустая строка (вывожу с помощью `CMSException::printStackTrace()`)

В чем ошибка? Что делать с `amq-client.ts`?
Может кто-нибудь дать инструкцию по-шагам? Или хотя бы намек куда копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу на свой вопрос на случай, если кто-нибудь столкнется с такой задачей.
Допустим, что у вас есть два ключа **xxx-machine-client.ks** и **xxx-machine-client.ts** и вам надо сделать из них соответственно **xxx-client.pem** и **xxx-server.pem**
Делаем так:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore xxx-machine-client.ks \
       -destkeystore xxx-client.p12 \
       -srcstoretype jks \
       -deststoretype pkcs12


openssl pkcs12 -in xxx-client.p12 -out xxx-client.pem

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore xxx-machine-client.ts \
       -destkeystore xxx-server.p12 \
       -srcstoretype jks \
       -deststoretype pkcs12

openssl pkcs12 -in xxx-server.p12 -out xxx-server.pem
```

То есть делаем через промежуточное звено `.p12`.

И мне еще понадобилось сопоставить IP сервера с **CN** сертификата (**Common Name**) в `/etc/hosts`. Например:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
xx.xx.xx.xx turambar-barmator
```

И использовать именно этот хост при коннекте.

Посмотреть данные сертификата можно так:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore xxx-machine-client.ks
```

Все, кладем пэмы в какое угодно место и указываем до них путь и пароли в `decaf::lang::System::setProperty`